# Filled contour plot on a nonrectangular grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, plotly-python

I have the following contour plot in matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]])
y = np.array([[9,8,6], [10,9,7], [11,10,8]])
z = np.array([[80,90,80], [85,100,90], [80,90,80]])

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
cont = ax1.contourf(x, y, z)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cont)
plt.plot(x[0,:], y[0,:], '-ok')
plt.plot(x[1,:], y[1,:], '-ok')
plt.plot(x[2,:], y[2,:], '-ok')
```

[image: Correct]

I'm trying to convert in to plotly in order to have an interactive figure in the web browser. I managed to create contour plots on a rectangular x-y grid using plotly, but is it possible to use a full meshgrid of x, y, z like in matplotlib's contourf? Below plotly code which doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
x = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]])
y = np.array([[9,8,6], [10,9,7], [11,10,8]])
z = np.array([[80,90,80], [85,100,90], [80,90,80]])
contourdata = go.Contour(x=x, y=y, z=z)
fig = go.Figure(data = contourdata)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x[0,:], y=y[0,:], mode='lines+markers',line=dict(color='black')))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x[1,:], y=y[1,:], mode='lines+markers',line=dict(color='black')))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x[2,:], y=y[2,:], mode='lines+markers',line=dict(color='black')))
fig.write_html('test.html', auto_open=True)
```

[image: Wrong]

I could use mpld3, but I would prefer not to. If plotly doesn't support this, is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2):

I found that the function I've been looking for isn't Contour but rather Contourcarpet
https://plot.ly/python/carpet-contour/

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]])
y = np.array([[9,8,6], [10,9,7], [11,10,8]])
z = np.array([[80,90,80], [85,100,90], [80,90,80]])

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Carpet(
    a = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
    b = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    x = x.flatten(),
    y = y.flatten(),
    aaxis = dict(
        showticklabels = "none",
        showgrid = False,
    ),
    baxis = dict(
        showticklabels = "none",
        showgrid = False,
    )
))

fig.add_trace(go.Contourcarpet(
    a = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
    b = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    z = z.flatten(),
    contours = dict(
        start = 80,
        end = 100,
        size = 1
    )
))

fig.write_html('test.html', auto_open=True)
```

[image]